# Restrict kivy's TextInput to only ascii characters

Tags: python, kivy, textinput

Please is there a way i can make a TextInput to disallow non ascii characters. So that when text is entered into the TextInput if a non-ascii character is typed it will not be added to TextInput. Just like the way one uses int filter, thus only whole numbers will be allowed in the TextInput
Please an example code would very be helpful. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

one potential solution is to use .decode() with the errors='ignore' flag on a string (eg of textinput). for example:

```
"food ресторан".decode("ascii", errors='ignore')
```

will replace all the chars it can to ascii silently

EDIT** updated example with przyczajony's suggestion to use filters:

```
class AsciiInput(TextInput):

    def insert_text(self, string, from_undo=False):
        string = string.decode("ascii", errors='ignore')
        return super(AsciiInput, self).insert_text(string, from_undo=from_undo)
```

Comment: thanks 4 d reply. But I'm still not clear on how to add it to d TextInput widget, I'm still new to kivy and python. Can you show me how. Thanks again...

Comment: hey guys, i really want to say a very big thank you for help. Espectially @ brmbigbang. Thanks for the examples they were absolutely perfect. I needed it for my app which is now almost complete... And i must say that stack overflow really rocks. Once again thank you

Answer (score 4):

TextInput filtering is described in docs, even with examples: [Filter](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.textinput.html#filtering)

Use regular expressions to check whenever the entered string contains wanted characters (`[A-Za-z0-9 ]`). If it passes, then return the string.